# SVG Icon not properly positioned on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this weird bug on Internet Explorer 11.

For my logo I use a **SVG** Icon and a **h2** element like this:

```
<div class="logo">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="svg" src="~/_img/logo.svg"/>
        <h2>Muffin-Welt.de</h2>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is the **CSS**:

```
.logo h2 {
    font-size: 33px;
    left: 80px;
    display: inline;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
}

.logo svg {
    width: 54px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.logo path {
    fill: #fff;
    transition: all ease 1s;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

On normal browsers this looks like this:

[image: This is how it's supposed to look like]

But for some reason it looks like this on IE11 (no other browsers)

[image]

I also have a testing domain of my web project where you can see the problem for yourself: http://test.muffin-welt.de/

Comment: I don't think the `position:absolute;` does what you want it to do, try removing that?

Comment: doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to include preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" in your svg tag. This fixed your problem on my end and I tested in Chrome, IE, and Firefox.

```css
body{ background-color: grey;}/* added so we can see results */
.logo h2 {
  font-size: 33px;
  left: 80px;
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}

.logo svg {
  width: 54px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.logo path {
  fill: #fff;
  transition: all ease 1s;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <a href="#">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 297 297" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
    <g>
      <path d="M148.5,212.002c-5.458,0-9.884,4.425-9.884,9.883v32.616c0,5.458,4.426,9.884,9.884,9.884c5.458,0,9.884-4.426,9.884-9.884
  v-32.616C158.384,216.427,153.958,212.002,148.5,212.002z" />
      <path d="M104.922,220.55c-0.737-5.408-5.71-9.194-11.129-8.457c-5.408,0.737-9.194,5.72-8.457,11.128l4.448,32.616
  c0.675,4.955,4.914,8.549,9.78,8.549c0.444,0,0.895-0.03,1.348-0.092c5.408-0.737,9.194-5.72,8.457-11.129L104.922,220.55z" />
      <path d="M203.207,212.093c-5.414-0.739-10.392,3.05-11.129,8.457l-4.447,32.615c-0.737,5.409,3.049,10.392,8.457,11.129
  c0.453,0.062,0.903,0.092,1.348,0.092c4.866,0,9.105-3.595,9.78-8.549l4.448-32.616
  C212.401,217.813,208.615,212.83,203.207,212.093z" />
      <path d="M289.359,156.654c0-30.362-15.107-62.087-41.448-87.04c-16.82-15.936-36.479-27.493-57.5-34.118
  C187.061,15.383,169.548,0,148.5,0s-38.562,15.383-41.911,35.496c-21.021,6.625-40.68,18.183-57.5,34.118
  c-26.342,24.953-41.448,56.678-41.448,87.04c0,18.932,12.597,35.007,29.942,40.486l7.808,63.71
  C47.835,280.784,66.161,297,86.241,297h124.518c20.08,0,38.406-16.216,40.851-36.149l7.793-63.588
  C276.733,191.898,289.359,175.725,289.359,156.654z M148.5,19.767c12.535,0,22.732,10.197,22.732,22.732
  c0,12.535-10.197,22.732-22.732,22.732s-22.732-10.197-22.732-22.732C125.768,29.964,135.965,19.767,148.5,19.767z
   M231.989,258.445c-1.249,10.184-10.972,18.788-21.23,18.788H86.241c-10.259,0-19.981-8.604-21.23-18.788l-7.338-59.877
  c10.252-1.711,19.274-7.102,25.654-14.768c7.897,9.375,19.791,15.353,33.07,15.353c13.01,0,24.664-5.946,32.419-15.281
  c7.849,9.335,19.644,15.281,32.813,15.281c13.01,0,24.664-5.946,32.419-15.281c6.319,7.515,15.198,12.826,25.289,14.615
  L231.989,258.445z M246.86,179.386c-12.676,0-22.989-10.197-22.989-22.731c0-5.459-4.425-9.884-9.883-9.884
  c-5.458,0-9.884,4.425-9.884,9.884c0,12.534-10.082,22.731-22.476,22.731c-12.676,0-22.988-10.197-22.988-22.731
  c0-5.459-4.426-9.884-9.884-9.884c-5.458,0-9.884,4.425-9.884,9.884c0,12.534-10.082,22.731-22.476,22.731
  c-12.601,0-23.245-10.409-23.245-22.731c0-5.459-4.426-9.884-9.884-9.884c-5.458,0-9.884,4.425-9.884,9.884
  c0,12.534-10.197,22.731-22.731,22.731c-12.601,0-23.246-10.409-23.246-22.731c0-24.592,13.188-51.766,35.276-72.689
  c13.436-12.73,28.928-22.233,45.469-28.142c5.604,16.925,21.567,29.175,40.348,29.175s34.744-12.25,40.348-29.175
  c16.542,5.908,32.032,15.411,45.469,28.142c22.089,20.924,35.276,48.098,35.276,72.689
  C269.593,169.189,259.396,179.386,246.86,179.386z" />
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <h2>Muffin-Welt.de</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, it was a learning experience for me too. I'd never heard of svg before seeing this question, so with this new knowledge I may start using them too. :D